# ExoPlayer resume on same position on rotate screen

Tags: android, video, android-activity, exoplayer, landscape-portrait

I am using ExoPlayer in my activity,What i want is to smoothly play video in portrait and landscape mode.For this purpose what I am doing is in `onpause` I save the currentPlayerPosition and seek player to that position in `onresume` but while rotating it face a jerk and video is stopped for a while and played to the saved position.

My code is below please help me how i can smoothly switch the mode portrait and landscape.Thanks

```
     @Override
public void onPause() {

    super.onPause();

    if (mExoPlayerView != null && mExoPlayerView.getPlayer() != null) {
        mResumeWindow = mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().getCurrentWindowIndex();
        mResumePosition = Math.max(0, mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().getContentPosition());
        mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().release();
    }
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mExoPlayerView.getPlayer() != null)
        mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().release();
}


  @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    outState.putInt(STATE_RESUME_WINDOW, mResumeWindow);
    outState.putLong(STATE_RESUME_POSITION, mResumePosition);
    outState.putBoolean(STATE_PLAYER_FULLSCREEN, mExoPlayerFullscreen);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}



   @Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    if (mExoPlayerView == null) {

        mExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.exoplayer);

        videoURL = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        postID = getIntent().getIntExtra("UserID", 0);

        String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(Vid.this, getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().packageName);
        DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory httpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent, null, DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, true);
        DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(Vid.this, null, httpDataSourceFactory);
        Uri daUri = Uri.parse(videoURL);

        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

        if (daUri.toString().startsWith("https://player.vimeo"))
            mVideoSource = new HlsMediaSource(daUri, dataSourceFactory, 1, null, null);
        else
            mVideoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(daUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

        initExoPlayer();

    } else {
        resumeExoPlayer();
    }

}


   private void resumeExoPlayer() {

    boolean haveResumePosition = mResumeWindow != C.INDEX_UNSET;

    if (haveResumePosition) {
        hideKeyboard();
        hideProgress();
        mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().seekTo(mResumeWindow, mResumePosition);
    }
}

private void initExoPlayer() {
    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
    LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
    SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(new DefaultRenderersFactory(this), trackSelector, loadControl);
    mExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

    boolean haveResumePosition = mResumeWindow != C.INDEX_UNSET;

    if (haveResumePosition) {
        hideKeyboard();
        hideProgress();
        mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().seekTo(mResumeWindow, mResumePosition);

    }

    mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().prepare(mVideoSource);
    mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().setPlayWhenReady(true);

    mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

            if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED) {
                hideProgress();
                mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().seekTo(0);
                mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().setPlayWhenReady(false);
            } else if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING) {
            } else if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY) {
                hideProgress();

                if (preferenceManager.getLoggedIn()) {
                    APIGetComment();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
            hideProgress();
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekProcessed() {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Player preparation takes time. You cant do much about it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Finally, After wasting 2 days I found it.
Simple add it in the manifest and will work on all android version ?

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection"
```

cheers!

Comment: thanks you, Yes, it solves the problem, for newbie like me, you will need to look for your video-activity in 'AndroidManifest.xml' and place it in the "<activity ... " definition.

Comment: Yeah please don't do this. This 'workaround' results in lots of other issues in your app including wrong layouts being displayed when rotating the device or enabling split screen.

Comment: You shouldn't need to prevent configuration changes for this to work. This solution should work https://stackoverflow.com/a/62427122/4052264

Answer (score 3):

No need of any additional coding, simply add this line

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

in your `AndroidManifest.xml`'s activity section.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the video to resume on orientation change, you can add this to your manifest `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`

```
     <activity
     <activity
         android:name=".MainActivity"
         android:name=".MainActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
+            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_2">
         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_2">
         <intent-filter>
         <intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also wasted quite a lot time in this. Take a look at it EXO PLAYER 2.11.2

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.2'
```

STEP - 1  Make an activity in which string url is passed as intent.

```
  public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity {

  public static final String sURL_KEY = "STREAMING_URL_KEY";
  public static final String sTOAST_TEXT = "Unable to stream, no media found";
  static final String LOADING = "PLAYER_LOADING";
  static final String STOPPED = "PLAYER_STOPPED";
  static final String PAUSED = "PLAYER_PAUSED";
  static final String PLAYING = "PLAYER_PLAYING";
  static final String IDLE = "PLAYER_IDLE";
  private static final String TAG = "StreamMediaActivity";
  int orientation;
  private Uri streamUrl;
  private SimpleExoPlayer mPlayer;
  private PlayerView playerView;
  private ProgressBar progressBar;
  private String mPlayerStatus;
  private long mPlaybackPosition = 0L;
  private boolean mIsPlayWhenReady = true;
  private int mCurrentWindow = 0;
  private Display display;
  private String STATE_RESUME_WINDOW = "resumeWindow";
  private String STATE_RESUME_POSITION = "resumePosition";
  private String STATE_PLAYER_FULLSCREEN = "playerFullscreen";
  private boolean mExoPlayerFullscreen = false;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    fullScreen();
    display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    orientation = display.getRotation();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);
    playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar_player);

// Pass a string uri to this class
    String urlString = getIntent().getStringExtra(sURL_KEY);
    if (urlString != null) {
      streamUrl = Uri.parse(urlString);
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(this, sTOAST_TEXT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      finish();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    initPlayer();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mPlaybackPosition != 0L && mPlayer != null) {
      mPlayer.seekTo(mCurrentWindow, mPlaybackPosition);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
  }

  @Override protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releasePlayer();
  }



    private void initPlayer() {
        // ESTABLISH THE DATA SOURCE FROM URL
    // here i'm playing local video file that's
 // why using the DefaultDataSourceFactory but you 
//may use DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory to stream 
//online videos 
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
            new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, getApplicationInfo().name));

    MediaSource mediaSource =
        new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(
            streamUrl);


    // CREATE A NEW INSTANCE OF EXO PLAYER
    if (mPlayer == null) {
      mPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this, new DefaultRenderersFactory(this)).build();
      playerView.setPlayer(mPlayer);
      progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(mIsPlayWhenReady);
    mPlayer.seekTo(mCurrentWindow, mPlaybackPosition);

    // PREPARE MEDIA PLAYER
    mPlayer.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
    mPlayer.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
        switch (playbackState) {
          case Player.STATE_BUFFERING:
            mPlayerStatus = LOADING;
            runOnUiThread(() -> progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE));
            break;
          case Player.STATE_ENDED:
            mPlayerStatus = STOPPED;
            break;
          case Player.STATE_READY:
            mPlayerStatus = (playWhenReady) ? PLAYING : PAUSED;
            runOnUiThread(() -> progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE));
            break;
          default:
            mPlayerStatus = IDLE;
            break;
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
        Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
      }
    });
  }

  @Override protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    mExoPlayerFullscreen = !mExoPlayerFullscreen;
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_RESUME_WINDOW, mCurrentWindow);
    outState.putLong(STATE_RESUME_POSITION, mPlaybackPosition);
    outState.putBoolean(STATE_PLAYER_FULLSCREEN, mExoPlayerFullscreen);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  }

  public void fullScreen() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  }

  private void releasePlayer() {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
      mPlayer.stop();
      mPlaybackPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
      mCurrentWindow = mPlayer.getCurrentWindowIndex();
      mIsPlayWhenReady = mPlayer.getPlayWhenReady();
      playerView.setPlayer(null);
      mPlayer.release();
      mPlayer = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Step 2 : Make the XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

  <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        app:use_controller="true"
        app:resize_mode="fit"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar_player"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

  </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

STEP 3: start VideoPlayerActivity using intent from another activity

```
Intent streamVideoIntent = new Intent(context, VideoPlayerActivity.class);
                        streamVideoIntent.putExtra(sURL_KEY, stringUrl);
                        context.startActivity(streamVideoIntent);
```

STEP 4 : Lastly add activity to manifest

```
<activity android:name=".ui.videoplayer.VideoPlayerActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection"
        />
```